# SimpleDateFormat vs DateFormat vs Joda-Time : Which one should be preferred with Kotlin?

Tags: android, jodatime, datetime-format, simpledateformat, date-format

Which one is the most efficient in handling and formatting dates, and also avoids unnecessary dependencies on third-party components?

Comment: Use the Java 8 date/time APIs, available on a wide range of devices through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Joda-time is a third-party component.

Comment: I considered voting to close this as opinion-based, but decided not to. The answer is not that opinion-based: use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Undoubtedly, `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API, and part of the standard library, is the most recommended option as of now.

#### `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`:

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (which extends `java.text.DateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

#### Joda-Time API:

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

Moreover, Joda-Time API is not the standard API of Java; rather, it's a 3rd party library.

#### `java.time` API:

This is the modern Date-Time API and was introduced with Java SE 8, as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html), to model [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards. You can learn about `java.time` API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I have seen many questions and comments related to this. I wonder why java.util and SimpleDateFormat have not been deprecated yet.

Comment: @LabGecko, most of the things in [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are already deprecated.